# Creating random list of number in python within certain range

Tags: python, random

I want to create 10,000 random numbers withing the range of 1 to 100.

How can I do with python?

I can use for loop and with each for loop I can use `random.sample()` or `random.random()` function.

Is there any other way, without using any for loop I can generate it with built-in function ?

Comment: `[rand.randrange(1,100) for _ in range(10000)]` should do. But maybe you've got demands for no-repeats, etc... we don't know

Comment: What is wrong with using `random.sample(range(1,100), 10000)` exactly? (for sampling without replacement or `random.choices()` with replacement)

Comment: Now, when you say "I can use random.sample or random.random() function.", do you mean "I know I can use sample() or random(), but I am receptive to using other functions from the random module", or do you mean "for this assignment, I am allowed to use _only_ sample() and random(), and all other functions are off limits, which is why I'm not using randint()"?

Comment: @Chris_Rands with `random.sample(range(1,100), 10000)` you will get error `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I can use for loop but i want to avoid it

Comment: @Chris_Rands sample can not be larger than population.. Thats the problem

Comment: @Kevin This is not a homework. I want to use it for optimization of time. Because may be in future if there are millions of words it can handle efficiently for my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For python 3.6:

```
import random

my_randoms = random.choices(range(1,100), k=10000)
print(my_randoms)
```

For older would still need to use loops:

```
my_randoms = [random.randrange(100) for x in range(10000)]
```

Comment: thanks. Its working perfectly in python 3. I can use it. Do you know anything similar in python 2. As I go through python 2 documentation. I didn't found any.

Comment: can you specify the min version of python to use this? it is at least 3.5 or 3.6